# How can I get rid of the text next to the navigation back button in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get rid of the text and just have the back arrow show up for ALL view controllers that show up on the navigation stack.

I already know that this code will work to remove the text on a single view controller:

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
```

However, I am looking for a solution where I don't have to copy and paste code into each individual view controller.

I am already subclassing every single navigation controller in my app to the same class, so I'm trying to find a solution I can write once in this UINavigationController subclass that will cause all children view controllers that might show up on the stack to show only the back arrow with no text.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing UINavigationControllerDelegate like this:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
}
```

backBarButtonItem is nil by default and it affects next pushed controller, so you just set it for all controllers

Answer (score 0):

In your case better option is to select the navigation item of your controller and add space in the back button option. See below image for reference :

[image]

You don't have to write any code in this scenario.